# problem with UITableViewCell when customizing with an extended class

Tags: iphone, uitableview, customizing

I have 2 classes for a UITableViewCell that show different data but they use the same table.

I'm trying to populate the table in 2 steps by using a bool var, but it seems that I get an exception because the cell gains the first class assignment and can't mutate...

basicaly I have to cell extended classes

```
@interface PatientsCellNewPager : UITableViewCell { } 
@interface DoctorsCellNewPager : UITableViewCell { }
```

the code brakes when I'm at step 2 and trying to change the type of the cell and gives an exception at  `[cell setData:set cellid:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] ];`
on the phase==2 if block..

this is because cell according to the debugger still has the type DoctorsCellNewPager from the first initialization....

How can I do it otherwise?? 
It has to be on the same page using the same instance of the class but using multiple layouts and defining the cell layout the spot ..would be a terrible option

here's my code

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";



    if (phase==2) { //patient


        PatientsCellNewPager *cell =(PatientsCellNewPager *)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[PatientsCellNewPager alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }







        PatientsSet *set = (PatientsSet *)[patients_set objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       

        NSLog(@"logg %d",indexPath.row);    


        [cell setData:set cellid:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] ]; 




           return cell;

    }
    else if (phase==1) { //doctor


        DoctorsCellNewPager *cell =(DoctorsCellNewPager *)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[DoctorsCellNewPager alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }





            // Set up the cell

            DoctorsSet *set = (DoctorsSet *)[doctors_set objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      


              [cell setData:set cellid:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] pass:YES ];  





        return cell;


    }


    return nil;

}
```

here's my error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DoctorsCellNewPager setData:cellid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181690'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x323ef64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x36632c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x323f31bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x323f2649 ___forwarding___ + 508
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very common issue and many people came across that - Just recently I had to deal with that issue, too.

Matt Gallagher posted a great tutorial on how to accomplish that on his blog:

[***Heterogeneous cells in a UITableViewController***](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/heterogeneous-cells-in.html)

---

Well, I just got an idea on how it could work..
// ***THIS IS HIGHLY EXPERIMENTAL AND HAS NOT BEEN TESTED***:

```
static NSString *PatientsCellIdentifier = @"PatientsCellNewPager";
static NSString *DoctorsCellIdentifier = @"DoctorsCellNewPager";

UITableViewCell *cell;
if(patient) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PatientsCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
        reuseIdentifier:PatientsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Setup cell for patient -> maybe you could use -configureCell:atIndexPath:
} else if (doctor) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
        reuseIdentifier:DoctorsCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Setup cell for doctor -> maybe you could use -configureCell:atIndexPath:
}

return cell;
```

Let me know if this brought you any further..

HTH

Comment: this is not a very elegant solution, I'm sure there has to be some way to cast the type of the cells

Comment: just updated the answer, is this something you're looking for?

Comment: WOW, this worked :) I think that this is how the compiler knows that the cells are actually different. Thank you !!!you're the man

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the `pass:..` param on the end, and the method you are calling, `[DoctorsCellNewPager setData:celled:]`, doesn't have the parameter `pass` set. So add the `pass` parameter and it should run fine.

Comment: the other one doesn't have that argument, I've quit it on purpose to see if that was causing the problem... the problem is the type of the cell that somehow remains as the first assigned